# Wordpress loop outputting posts with a weird CSS styling

Tags: wordpress, css

My wordpress loop is outputting posts in a weird format.

When I have 3 posts, everything was inline. However, now when I have 5 posts, they are displaying in a weird way (see attached image). The arrow shows how I would like the post to display.[image: Loop ddisplay]

Here is the html&php of the page

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <?php

               $args1 = array( 'post_type' => array('case_studies'), 'order' => 'DESC', 'posts_per_page' => 30, 'orderby' => 'date' );
               $loop = new WP_Query( $args1 );

               while ( $loop->have_posts() ) { 

               $loop->the_post();

               $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($loop->ID));

            ?>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="blog_blocks">
                    <div class="b_image">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="b_h_sec">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_excerpt(), true ); ?></p>
                    <span class="r_m">Read More</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The actual page you can be seen here [here](https://www.lionbusinessmedia.com/case-studies/) - maybe seeing the CSS in Chrome tools will help.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your div :

```
<div class="row">
```

Add a "**d-flex**" class :

```
<div class="row d-flex">
```

On **d-flex** class, add this properties CSS :

```
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Enjoy ! ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's because these blocks all have `float: left`, and the third block is a little less high than the previous one, so the fourth block is also floated left next to the second one. That's in the nature of floats.

One solution would be to use fixed common heights. Another would be to add `clear: left` to the fourth block, but that isn't responsive - it will *always*  move that block to a new line even if there is enough space for it to fit into the current line.

A safer working solution would be to use `display: flex` on the container, with `flex-wrap: wrap` added.